# supervisor exiting with ENOENT

Tags: django, gunicorn, supervisord

I am attempting to deploy a Django web application for the first time using NGINIX, Gunicorn and Supervisor on Digital Ocean Ubuntu 16.04 server. I am following the [this linked tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/10/16/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-7.html).

I am having a trouble configuring Supervisor. When running this command...

```
sudo supervisorctl status automatedre
```

I get this error...

```
automatedre               FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

The log file shows this...

```
supervisor: couldn't exec /home/automatedre/gunicorn_start: ENOENT
supervisor: child process was not spawned
supervisor: couldn't exec /home/automatedre/gunicorn_start: ENOENT
supervisor: child process was not spawned
```

**/home/automatedre/gunicorn_start**

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="django_automatedre"
DIR=/home/automatedre/automatedre
USER=automatedre
GROUP=automatedre
WORKERS=3
BIND=unix:/home/automatedre/run/gunicorn.sock
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=automatedre.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=automatedre.wsgi
LOG_LEVEL=error

cd $DIR
source ../venv/bin/activate

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DIR:$PYTHONPATH

exec ../venv/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $WORKERS \
  --user=$USER \
  --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=$BIND \
  --log-level=$LOG_LEVEL \
  --log-file=-
```

**/etc/supervisor/conf.d/automatedre.conf**

```
[program:automatedre]
command=/home/automatedre/gunicorn_start
user=automatedre
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/automatedre/logs/gunicorn.log
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. I don't believe it is a file permission issue since I previously changed permission on *gunicorn_start* with this...

```
chmod u+x gunicorn_start
```

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I previously left out the text below from the log file because I didn't think it was relevant...mistake.

```
/home/automatedre/gunicorn_start: 2: /home/automatedre/gunicorn_start: ^M: not found
/home/automatedre/gunicorn_start: 12: /home/automatedre/gunicorn_start: ^M: not found
/home/automatedre/gunicorn_start: 13: cd: can't cd to /home/automatedre/automatedre^M
/home/automatedre/gunicorn_start: 14: /home/automatedre/gunicorn_start: source: not found
/home/automatedre/gunicorn_start: 15: /home/automatedre/gunicorn_start: ^M: not found
/home/automatedre/gunicorn_start: 18: /home/automatedre/gunicorn_start: ^M: not found
/home/automatedre/gunicorn_start: 19: exec: ../venv/bin/gunicorn: not found
```

I initially created the **/home/automatedre/gunicorn_start** and **/etc/supervisor/conf.d/automatedre.conf** in my Brackets text editor on my windows machine which created this issue.

After doing some more digging, I learned that [Windows/MS-DOS uses CR+LF to indicate end-of-lines and UNIX uses LF character to indicate line termination (EOL character)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56024/bash-korn-shell-script-edited-on-windows-throws-error-m-not-found).

This difference resulted in the ^M at the end of each line causing the file path not found error.

Recreating each file from the terminal with nano solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To get more info you could change `LOG_LEVEL=error` to `LOG_LEVEL=debug`.

Comment: Thanks Ralf. This will be helpful in my future debugging adventures.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone have this same issue and have already verified that the `directory` path is OK, go and check that there are no leading spaces on the lines of the configuration file for this specific unit or rule for the program.

wrong:

```
[program:celerybeat]
   command=/usr/...
   directory=/home/...
   user=...
...
```

Right

```
[program:celerybeat]
command=/usr/...
directory=/home/...
user=...
```